# Create AppDomainSetup in DLL for POS for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, pos-for-.net, appdomainsetup

We currently have a POS application where the main WPF App is running on .NET 4.8 and all the other DLLs on .net standard 2.0. But now we want to upgrade to .NET 6. After some research we saw that POS for .NET 1.14.1 doesn't support .NET Core. So we left the DLL that uses Microsoft.PointOfService.dll on .NET 4.8.1. But we still get the error:

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception.
Method not found: 'Void System.AppDomainSetup.set_ApplicationBase(System.String)'.
```

Is it possible to create a `AppDomainSetup` just in the DLL? Or do we have to leave the main WPF App on .NET 4.8 too?

Comment: You can always host `Microsoft.PointOfService.dll` in a separate process and use some kind of IPC to communicate. But since .NET Core (and .NET 5+) support for AppDomains was removed.